# How do you counter a throw?

Tags: blazblue-calamity-trigger

I just played my first ranked match online in *BlazBlue: Calamity Trigger*, and my opponent did a chain-throw with Jin that I couldn't escape. It was the same sequence of hits over and over, freezing me in place each time to set up the next one.

I'm sure that the game is well-designed enough that I could have gotten out of it if I knew what I was doing, but I didn't know what I was doing, and lost to it.

How can I counter the throw so that I can escape this trap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, the same button combination used for initiating a throw is also the one used for escaping from a throw. Of course, since I am unaware of the particular combo you were subjected to, it is hard to say what your options were, exactly.

The game actually gives you a visual cue which indicates moments when you can escape from a throw. Green or purple exclamation marks above your head indicate a window of opportunity to escape a throw. If they appear with a red X over them, that means you cannot escape the current throw.

All of this is covered in [this guide](http://blazblue.byethost13.com/bbct/system.html#throwescape) (scroll down a bit if it doesn't jump to the right location).